# Azure Mobileservice Table script respond: How to delete an item of the respond?

Tags: javascript, android, json, node.js, azure

I'm tyring to modify my respond from an Azure MobileService Table script. Let's say I'm posting the following JSON Object and Parameters to the table script (via Android/JAVA):

```
    JsonObject customUser = new JsonObject();
    customUser.addProperty("mail", mail);

    List<Pair<String,String>> parameters = new ArrayList<Pair<String, String>>();
    parameters.add(new Pair<String, String>("login", "true"));

    mTableAccounts.insert(customUser, parameters, callback);
```

I'm receving the JSON Object and the paramerts in my table script. How can I change the respond so that the script doesn't send the element item.mail?

```
function insert(item, user, request) {
delete item.mail;
request.respond(200, {
    test: "jooo123"
});}
```

The element item.mail is always be responded. How to change the respond so that the elements which are posted to the script aren't responded?